# Kubuntu 16.04.2 freezes, error message is ata1:COMRESET failed (errno=-16)

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, ssd

While using Kubuntu sometimes the interface freezes while the mouse moves but won't click anything, and when I hit the CTRL + ALT + F1 I got the - *ata1:comreset failed (errno=-16)* message.

I tested my SSD and the S.M.A.R.T tests are good and the disk is healthy according to KDE partition manager.

Update: Scanned the disk using all the tests in Parted Magic, came back clean. The only errors that showed up are the ata related ones.

The Sata disk is set to AHCI rather than compatible.

I'm using kernel 4.10 low latency.

My graphics card is intel 3000 and KDE is 5.5

Any idea on what causes these freezes?

---

Update #1: Updated KDE to 5.8.5

Update #2: Checksum of the downloaded iso didn't match but I installed it anyway.

---

Update: I forgot that I downloaded a bad iso, and reinstalling all the packages using synaptic seems to have done the trick so far, I'll update if the issue happens again!

Update #4: They still occur, but less frequent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hardware related and it was fixed by updating the firmware under Windows (because there is no software for Linux). Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You have stated that your checksum does not match the one here which is already a really bad sign likely meaning corruption and should usually indicate a need for reinstallation: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/xenial/release/SHA256SUMS

You have stated you don't want to reinstall, but unfortunately, it seems like that is may be the only option. You could try using a different mouse and keyboard and see if that prevents the freezing, or possibly try a different desktop environment instead and see if that helps - I suggest trying XFCE.

To install XFCE, open up a terminal window and type the following command:

`sudo apt install xfce4`

Once you have installed XFCE, you should log out and log in using the XFCE desktop environment and see if that helps.

You can also try reinstalling all packages with apt-get. To do this, open up a terminal window and type this:

`dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | awk '{print $1}' > list.log
awk '$1=$1' ORS=' ' list.log > newlist.log
apt-get install --reinstall $(cat newlist.log)`

If this does not work, you could try this command instead:

`for pkg in dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v '(dpkg|apt|mysql|mythtv)' ; do apt-get -y --force-yes install --reinstall $pkg ; done`

All of the packages should be reinstalled and hopefully that should do the trick and fix your issue. You could also try using Synaptic to reinstall your packages and hopefully that will help.

If not, it is likely that you will need to reinstall Kubuntu and this time verify that the downloaded ISO checksum matches the valid checksum.

sources:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79125/reinstalling-all-debian-packages
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=735693

Comment: Hello @i_pk_pjers_i. I reinstalled all the packages using Synaptic, over 1 GB of download and so far things are good, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes internet downloads get corrupted. 
The SHA256SUMS file is there: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/xenial/release/SHA256SUMS . Just in case, do you want to check if the Kubuntu iso file is correct?

If the Kubuntu iso file is correct: using a virtual machine to try your configuration is a good next step, then seeing if everything works well there, or if a bug report has to be be opened.

Comment: I have to admit that the sum wasn't exactly correct but I installed it anyway, and I used a torrent so it won't break!

Comment: If the checksum is different, **the ISO, and thus your install, is corrupted**.  At this point, your best bet is to reinstall, as there is no telling what parts of your install are broken.

Comment: @QwertyChouskie I installed a new kernel and the system now is updated from 16.04.1 to 16.04.2, and the interface is 5.8.5 via backports. Doesn't that count as a reinstall?

Comment: Chances are, there are still some corrupted files somewhere.  You could try using `aptitude` to run the "reinstall" action on the entire "Installed Packages" section.

Comment: I am using Synaptic, would marking all installed packages and reinstalling them do the trick? It's over 1 GB of download. @QwertyChouskie

Comment: Probably, though I am not familiar with Synaptic.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in kernels: 2.6.27-5 and 2.6.27-7, but I'm sure you have an updated kernel since your OS version is 16.04.2 .

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/256637

A user here resolved the same issue after upgrading the SSD firmware.

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/7231/how-to-triage-comreset-failed-error-at-startup/

Comment: My kernel is 4.10 and my laptop is Lenovo, I've been running the laptop with Linux for years without an error, and had Ubuntu gnome for over 10 months without it occurring, so I'd rule out BIOS and SSD firmware.

Comment: I've found a frimware update for my SSD, but it's for windows (of course) and I guess I'll have to install wine to be able to use it (that if it works).

Comment: To update the drive firmware and BIOS, I would use this: https://gbatemp.net/threads/medicat-dvd-a-multiboot-linux-dvd.361577/ The "Mini Windows 10" can be used to run the update EXEs.

Comment: @QwertyChouskie just went over to the mini windows 10 page, the smallest version of it is 1.7 GB! I'm better off downloading Kubuntu 16.04.2 or reinstalling my whole packages without touching the firmware, because I'm not sure if data loss is involved with it or not.

Comment: You could also try F4UBCD (https://falconfour.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/falconfours-ultimate-boot-cd-v4-61-patch/) as it fits on a CD.